How would an ancient Chinese necromancer keep his skeletons burning?
During the Xi dynasty of Ancient China, Zhang Xianzhong accidentally gained the power to animate and control the dead by supernaturally puppeteering the corpses like extremely sophisticated marionettes or remote-controlled robots, giving the appearance of resurrection. Essentially, he's a necromancer trying to conquer Ancient China with his zombie army.
When his zombies rot to the point of skeletonization, Zhang Xianzhong turns some of his skeletons into "Hungry Ghosts". Hungry Ghosts are skeletons that are constantly on fire from head to toe. The Hungry Ghosts are meant to terrorize soldiers or linger around strongholds menacingly during night time, exploiting the fear of ghosts and the living dead. At a minimum, he requires his Hungry Ghosts to burn for 12 hours as they'll act only at night. Furthermore, the skeletons should still recognizably appear as a skeleton for any viewer so no wrappings. He doesn't mind if the skeletons are destroyed after the burning as long as they serve their purpose. The flames don't need to be powerful, just that it covers the entire skeleton.
Under these specific historical and technical conditions, is there a way for him to keep his Hungry Ghosts burning?

If you've already got resurrection, it seems a minor step to add in the flame as a power. What is the need to explain it via scientific methods?

I like the premise but I can't work out what sort of answer are you  looking for. Generally magical elements can be taken as metaphor for emotions, surely fire=anger. The solution is obvious, the necromancer would insult: their mothers, kittens,  their hairstyle, manhood etc. until they're pissed off enough to combust.

I would suggest changing 'ancient' to 'pre-industrial'. Ancient usually refers to times more than about 1500 years ago.

@Kilisi I'm putting words in L.Dutch's mouth, but I'd have voted to delete as not an answer. Dmyt isn't stupid and certainly knows magic could be used to do this, but while he should have been explicit (Dmyt...), we know from experience he/she's asking from an "other than magic..." perspective. In other words, "what would the mage soak the skeletons in and light that would burn for 12 hours?"

And on top of not being specific about what kind of answer you're looking for, Dmyt, you just asked how this necromancer would keep the skeletons from rotting. Please do not start asking a lot of questions about every aspect of how the necromancer can use/effect these skeletons (it's been done before and it really irritates us). Remember, we're not a free research service. You're obligated to perform your own research and explain why your effort failed. We'll hold you to that obligation more with each question.

And while we're at it, to avoid a VTC:Needs More Details, please [edit] your post and explain (a) whether it's OK that the skeleton is consumed by the fire in 12 hours, (b) the hoped-for height of the flame (a roaring fire obscures the skeleton as effectively as wrappings), (c) the atmospheric conditions this flame will experience, (d) whether the flame must be visible during the day (flame color).

the real problem you have is bone is flamable, unless you bleach the hell out of it at which point it is super brittle.

Furthermore, the skeletons should still recognizably appear as a skeleton for any viewer so no wrappings. A skeleton can easily be still recognizable as such even with some covering, like some armor. More so when it is so well lit up as these ones will be.

@JBH yeah, best to keep out of other guys mouths

@Kilisi Look at those two comment upvotes... Wonderful! And your comment seems to have gone missing....

@JBH lmao.... thats what happens when you're in peoples mouths I guess... ahaha thanks for the laugh

The fire doesn't need to be that big to make it look like a full skeleton. I also don't think the question is unanswerable.
Drill holes into the skeleton big enough for wicks to pass through. Seal the skeleton with (unflammable) wax. Fill it with oil they use for candles.
The skeleton won't be on fire on every inch of it's body, but you aren't getting close to your opponents you are just scaring them. So a skeleton with flames sprouting from it's frame would be good enough.
Bonus: anyone who does get close and hacks at them is likely to break the skeleton and the contents will spill out and catch fire.

A quick google search suggests that ~3 ounces of lamp oil will keep a lamp lit overnight. So for 100 lamp-lights on your skeleton, you'd need about 2.5 gallons of oil. That almost certainly won't fit in the bones (even if you use the head!) but could easily fit in a bladder-backpack. BUT(!) keep in mind that a strong wind will blow your ghost out. There's a reason "hurricane lamps" have glass enclosures.

@codeMonkey If we're getting fancy, you could mount glass around the skeleton's head and shoulders, like a very unusual lantern, to keep the wicks burning.

@codeMonkey no you should be able to get that much space, ther is half a gallon of bone marrow in a person, another gallon the the skull and spine, you can manage another half gallon in trabecular space, then you only need some nooks and cranies for the last half gallon, assuming you don;t just use a few less wicks.

@John The whole torso could serve as a fuel canister. Cover the rib cage up with some (ancient) armor. Use the hollow marrow for tubing it around the skeleton. It both gives a plausible reason for there to be little flames on the torso -preserving fuel-, and hide the canister. For aesthetics, make some more flames come from the neckline in the armor. A nice bonus would be to make some way to have the fuel tank erupt as a last ditch suicide attack; Flaring-up the fire, possibly to the point of erupting over nearby enemies. This could even burn away all evidence of the mechanism.

This is mostly a frame challenge answer. It also is partly a highly illegal writing advice answer. Shhhh, don't snitch!
If the only magic is zombie-moving magic, you can't have this. Your fire is going to burn up all the connective tissues and severely damage the bones, and the whole thing would fall apart. Plus whatever fuel you're using will all burn up long before the time twelve hour time limit unless you're carrying many kilograms of it. Assuming a mass burning rate of $0.002kg/m^2s$ (very roughly the mass burning rate of a free-standing plank of wood) and a $1m^2$ surface area gets us about $100kg$ of fuel for 12 hours worth of seconds. Unless we give our guy something like molten uranium to burn then there's not even a point in trying to solve the engineering problems, there's simply no way to carry enough fuel and still look like a skeleton.
However, you don't need a non-magical source of fire if you want a character to prove to the other characters that the skeletons are not innately fire-skeletons. You can have the fire magic require some magical object that is separable from the skeleton. After taking an axe to the skeleton (who might be an invincible ghost, but we have to know for sure!) our intrepid empiricist gets some tongs and removes the ever-burning magic scrolls (etc) that the necromancer has tied inside the rib-cage, or something like that. Or if the villain is supposed to smugly boast to himself about how he has duped all his stupid enemies, he can have an inner monologue about his ever-burning magic scrolls (etc).
Bonus writing points if ever-burning magic scrolls (etc) are known in other circumstances, but wouldn't normally be able to produce the intended effect, except for a factor which is known separately to be true about the skeletons, so that the Case of the Burning Skeletons becomes a fair-play whodunnit.

To continue the math, 0.002 kg/s at 20 MJ/kg is... actually, a pretty dangerous fire, at 40 kW. A typical gas stove is only ~3 kW. You could get burned by tackling such a skeleton too closely, if not wearing protection. For intimidation purposes, less would suffice, though I doubt anyone would be intimidated after their first encounter.

Fire Gaki
When talking about specific creatures from myths and legends, it's often best to figure out the origins of these myths, and then fit that origen as best as you can to your setting.  The idea of Hungry Ghosts comes from one of the Hellish realms of reincarnation described in certain traditions of Buddhism.  In Japanese Buddhism specifically, Gaki are hungry ghosts that are damned to seek out and consume some manner of shameful or torturous food like rotten flesh or feces.  These ghosts do not like this food. Rather, their insatiable hunger for it is a form of punishment unto itself.
One variety of Gaki are said to seek out and consume fire.  This fire burns them as they eat it torturing the undead, but they can not help their cravings.  The food can never kill them no matter how awful it is, and they can never starve to death.  In mythology, these Gaki simply become fire breathing ghosts, but we can change this a bit to fit your setting.
So, the Necromancer can raise Gaki who are compelled to consume fire.  When they do, it burns away their flesh leaving nothing but dry, black bones, but they continue to eat and drink whatever burns because they must.  So, to keep your skeletons burning, you simply need to keep them near a source of fuel.  Imagine large cauldrons of burning oil near your gate.  Your Fire Gaki would simply stand around the cauldrons constantly trying to drink the burning oil, then when an intruder shows up, they are covered by all the burning oil they were trying desperately to consume.
So, instead of keeping the skeletons themselves burning for 12 hours, you just need to keep your cauldrons burning, and the skeletons will keep themselves covered in fresh coats of burning fuel until you need them.

Undead fireflies.  The Necromancer has legions of eager followers willing to search the grass and net the air for fireflies.  Fireflies have short lives, alas - but with the help of the Necromancer, they rise again.  They rot until they take on a gaunt skeletal appearance, which is to say, all the good bioluminescent goo has an opportunity to mix with enzymes and break down to release light.  But just as somehow the skeletons keep walking, the fireflies keep twitching - and their glow keeps shining.  These "Fire Seeds", as the Necromancer calls them when handing them out, are then painstakingly implanted into the Hungry Ghosts by innumerable minions using a sort of hook-and-latch sewing tool.  Each puncture is carefully cross-stitched and double-reinforced.  The sickly glowing goo drips out every pore of the Hungry Ghosts' skin... forever.

Since the flames don't have to do any damage or anything except giving out light at night, consider Baskerville-dogging your skeletons :)
Cover them in a phosphorescent compound - they will hauntingly glow through the night without any damage to their frames other fuel-based answers entail.
And they will recharge during the day

Frame challenge: The Skeleton that burns twice as bright burns half as long
Rather than an all body fire, consider the essentials. The skeletons keep tiny pilot light flames going in their eyes, from a tiny fuel source, essentially an oil lamp within the skull. However, your necromancer, wanting his zombies to last longer, used a nitrate based preservative. This, through a vague chemical process (i.e, I know you can get phosphorous from bone using nitric acid, but I don't remember how), has leached the phosphate ions from the skeleton's bones, transforming them into a thin layer of yellow phosphorous. This is carefully scraped from the inside of the skull, so as to stop premature ignition. It also glows slightly, giving them a ghostly appearance, though this eventually fades.
On seeing an enemy, the skeleton jams its thumbs into its eye sockets, before running screaming towards the enemy, wreathed in unquenchable chemical fire.

Skeletons having a skull 'pilot light', only to combust on detecting enemies seems almost game like, where a monster enters its hostile state when approached. Queue skeleton running into the nearest person before exploding. A nice way to conserve fuel too!

What is fire, exactly? For a physical way, coat the skeletons in radioluminescent paint. Glowing (and moving) skeletons will certainly strike fear and despair into the onlookers. The light will last for many years, if you choose the ingredients wisely.
If, later on, the necromancer becomes concerned with health or environmental issues, he can switch to non-radioactive phosphorescence substances. These will generally require to expose the skeletons to daylight, to absorb the energy for the night shift.

Environmental issues is exactly why real-life necromancers mostly stick to non-glowy vampires and zombies. Keep it biodegradable, stay away from NRC paperwork.
